# Inner Join between a Table and a View gives Cartesian product of both

Tags: sql, view, db2, inner-join

When I INNER JOIN a Table with a View, it gives me the cartesian product of both Table and View

I'm using DB2 database. I used INNER JOIN between table and View joining them based on a column which is present in both Table and View

```
select * FROM  MYSCHEMA.TABLE_A a INNER JOIN MYSCHEMA.MY_VIEW_A va on a.PRICE_ID=va.PRICE_ID
```

My Table is having total of 200 records and View returns 300 records. All PRICE_ID in TABLE_A matches with PRICE_ID column from View. Instead of returning 300 result set, I'm getting 60000 records while joining them.

Comment: it seems you have duplicate id in both tables

Comment: Check again the ON condition maybe you have a typo with the aliases `a` and `va`. Instead of `on a.PRICE_ID=va.PRICE_ID` is it  `on a.PRICE_ID=a.PRICE_ID` or `on va.PRICE_ID=va.PRICE_ID`?

Comment: @forpas: No Typo. I want to join on columns from table and View

Comment: @Rajeesh an INNER join would return the cartesian product as a result only if the condition in the ON clause is always TRUE. So double check your code and the data. Is there a case that PRICE_ID is the same in all rows in both tables?

Answer (score 1):

You would seem to have the same value of `PRICE_ID` in both tables.

This is easy enough to check for duplicates:

```
select PRICE_ID, count(*)
from MYSCHEMA.TABLE_A a
group by PRICE_ID
having count(*) > 1
order by count(*) desc;

select PRICE_ID, count(*)
from MYSCHEMA.MY_VIEW_A va
group by PRICE_ID
having count(*) > 1
order by count(*) desc;
```

The duplicates explain why you are getting so many rows.

Comment: Yes..column used for JOIN is duplicate in both table causing this result. I mat need to make it distinct in one of the table/view

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*
FROM MYSCHEMA.TABLE_A a
         INNER JOIN (select distinct PRICE_ID
                         MYSCHEMA.MY_VIEW_A) tmp on tmp.PRICE_ID = a.PRICE_ID
```

Comment: I need to get column from VIEW also in my result set. With this query it is not possible

Comment: since there are multiple rows in this view, some aggregation must be applied to the subquery (e.g. MIN, MAX, RANK)